# Swift 3 - Dynamically alter number of segments in a Segmented Control

Tags: swift, user-interface

The number of segments in my Segmented Control needs to change depending on the number of matching words the program finds.

Can I do this?

"mySegmentedControl.numberOfSegments" looks like the right command but doesn't work.

Comment: Hi - I read that posting and surely the number of segments should be dictatable with a command like, mySegmentedControl.numberOfSegments = X, in the same way the literals in segments can be. That is why I posted the questin and phrased it differently. Makybe I should have made the point stronger.  What they seem to be doing in starting with a nul segment controller and appending to it.

Comment: The code I used in the end was: for count in stride(from: 0, to: myArray.count, by: 1) {
            fromSegmentController.insertSegment(withTitle: "A1", at: count, animated: false)
        }